# any easy way to locate wrong java class file version in a list of jar files

Tags: java

somehow a jar file created with wrong jdk (jdk6) got stuck into a jdk 5 projects lib folder, I am trying to locate it. Right now the only method I have is using jclasslib on each and every class file. Is there an easier or faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line, you should be able to do this:
`javap -verbose YourClasshere.`  You'll be looking for the version part of the results.

If they are all in one directory, you can use `javap -verbose *.class`

There's a ton of stuff in there, you'll want to grep for major, or redirect it to a text file and search, something like that.

Comment: luckily I found an old version of the jdk5 code and was able to update rt.jar with custom logging to tell me. Oracle should really improve the logging and messages they inherited from Sun, sometimes its almost impossible to know what went wrong